# Unable to access each element from Object array in List in JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jstl

I am trying to access each element from Object array which is stored in a List but whenever I try to access it by index/properties of Model class its throws below exception

```
[2016/09/06 10:12:19:351 GMT+02:00] 00000049 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [/WEB-INF/views/instruction.jsp] in application [SpringMVCHibernate_war]. Exception created : [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type java.lang.Integer
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:232)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:209)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:319)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:89)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:55)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:174)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:778)
at com.ibm._jsp._instruction._jspx_meth_c_forEach_1(_instruction.java:133)
at com.ibm._jsp._instruction._jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(_instruction.java:184)
at com.ibm._jsp._instruction._jspx_meth_c_if_0(_instruction.java:227)
at com.ibm._jsp._instruction._jspService(_instruction.java:97)
```

Below is my jsp snippet:

```
       <c:forEach items="${listPersons}" var="listObj">
            <c:forEach items="${listObj}" var="instruction">
                <tr>
                    <td>${instruction[0]}</td>
                    <td>${instruction[1]}</td>
                    <td>${instruction[2]}</td>
                    <td>${instruction[3]}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
```

tried below way too but got same javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:

```
       <c:forEach items="${listPersons}" var="listObj">
            <c:forEach items="${listObj}" var="instruction">
                <tr>
                    <td>${instruction.iKey}</td>
                    <td>${instruction.sProc}</td>
                    <td>${instruction.bCurrency}</td>
                    <td>${instruction.wModified}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
```

where

```
    model.addAttribute("instruction", new Instruction());
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
```

and list is:

```
List<Object[]> personsList = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MyDB.INSTRUCTION").list();
```

below is sample list output:

```
[25258188, SP, IND, 2016-03-16 08:07:11.0]
[25258191, NR, USD, 2016-03-16 08:07:11.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   <c:forEach items="${listPersons}" var="listObj">
            <tr>
                <td>${listObj[0]}</td>
                <td>${listObj[1]}</td>
                <td>${listObj[2]}</td>
                <td>${listObj[3]}</td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) I thought it may need inner loop to get each element from Object[] and outer loop to iterate list, shouldn't it be like that?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this exception because your **instruction** variable in your JSP is not type of array or list
 its simple string or any other type, try to understand your flow and verify weather list Persons contains list inside  list or not

Comment: Thanks @Jekin, not sure where I mistaken as I was trying to access properties of Instruction class using instruction variable by doing: model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());